# jquery autocomplete delay not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have this in my autocomplete code.

Delay and minlength options are not working for me in Jquery Autocomplete

I tried putting sleep too in search function. even thats not working

What I am seeing on interface 1) "getTags" call getting executed even for 1/2 charactors and 2) Calls are being made instantaneously no delay whatsoever.

Please help

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        delay: 10000,
        serviceUrl: "getTags",
        minLength: 3,
        search: function( event, ui ) {
            sleepFor(2000);
            console.log("Searching for",event)
        }
});
```

Comment: can you create fiddle or code pen ?..i created one but could not replicate this issue - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/beBQRm

Comment: damn.. i edited ur code to get here http://codepen.io/premrajnarkhede/pen/RRoqOJ but here i am not even getting suggestions

Comment: did you try replacing serviceURL with source??

Comment: Thanks Sai.. Resolved issue..  Thanks for your help

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: @NagaSaiA Yes it did. I tried new code on example you had created and ported it back.. Thank you very much Credited you in answer

Comment: Thanks @TTA wiki. :).  Could you please mark my post as answered and vote ,if possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing service URL with source and created codepen for reference -

```
Source :"getTags"
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/beBQRm

Comment: it is not working on codepen link provided in answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys

There is some naive mistake on my side which became clear to me when I was trying to work on example provided by NagaSai refer to comments

I was referring to this https://designshack.net/articles/javascript/create-a-simple-autocomplete-with-html5-jquery/ and downloaded autocomplete-min.js

It wasn't needed and I was trying to use autcomplete jquery's documentation on this

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        delay: 2000,
        source: function (request, response) {
                    jQuery.get("getTags", {
                        query: request.term
                    }, function (data) {
                        // assuming data is a JavaScript array such as
                        // ["one@abc.de", "onf@abc.de","ong@abc.de"]
                        // and not a string
                        console.log(data)
                        response(data["suggestions"]);
                    });

                    //console.log("Here")
                    //data=["heyy"]
                    //response(data);
            },
        //source:"getTags",
        minLength: 1,
        search: function( event, ui ) {
            sleepFor(100);
            console.log("Searching for",event)
        }
});
```

This is working perfectly